# kendo ui checkbox check/unhceck issue

Tags: kendo-ui

I have an issue related to kendo UI checkbox selection.

In a kendow there is a Kendo checkbox and on selection of the checkox kendo dropdown is Enabling/Disabling.

Kendo window is opening on anchor click. On first time opening of window, checkbox is working fine. If I change the page and come again to that page and open the popup then checkbox is not able to check/uncheck.

Comment: Is there any errors in console? Do you have any function on window open/activate? If so can you provide it?

Comment: Sorry for late reply Jaroslaw. There is no error in console, value of checkbox i.e. True/False is fine in DOM but in GUI state of the checkbox is not changing.

Comment: Here is example I've prepared but I could not see error that you mentioned: http://dojo.telerik.com/EROJu. Try to reproduce your issue there or provide your widgets code (especially window and its events).

Comment: if (that.dialog == undefined || that.dialog == null) {
  that.dialog = $("#filterChecklistDialog").kendoWindow({
     title: "Checklist Filtering Options",
     model: true,
     resizable: false,
     visible: false,
      width: 650,
  });
}
that.dialog.data("kendoWindow").center().open();

Comment: Above is the code on Anchor click. I changed
from
that.dialog.data("kendoWindow").center().open();
to
$("#filterChecklistDialog").data('kendoWindow').center().open();
and then checkbox is working fine.
Thanks for your great support.